# Creating new user in Google Sheets using PHP

Tags: php, google-sheets

anybody have spare time to help me out, im trying to add a new users to a Google Sheets using PHP, it's for school requirements that when a students provide their emails then by PHP they are backend to add in the Google sheets as `viewer`

I already done some work here, I can successfully pull my data, however adding a new user cost be a 500 HTTP error. Idk if it was classes, I already tweak everything, but no hope in making it work. Thanks for your help in advance.

Here's the code

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

// Set up the client object with your credentials
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS);

// Create a new instance of the Sheets API service
$service = new Google_Service_Sheets($client);

// Set the spreadsheet ID and range of cells to retrieve
$spreadsheet_id = 'MYSHEETS_ID';
$range = 'Sheet1!A1:C10';

// Create a new permission object for the reader
$permission = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission();
$permission->setType('user');
$permission->setRole('reader');
$permission->setEmailAddress('studentsample@gmail.com');



try {
  // Make the request to the API to add the new reader
  $response = $service->permissions->create(
      $spreadsheet_id, 
      $permission, 
      array('sendNotificationEmail' => false)
  );
  // Print out the response
  print_r($response);
} catch (Google_Service_Exception $exception) {
  // Handle any exceptions that may have occurred
  echo 'An error occurred: ' . $exception->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: It looks like the code you provided is using the Google Drive API to add a new reader to a spreadsheet, rather than the Google Sheets API. The create() method is used to create a new permission, which allows a user to access a file or folder in Google Drive, but not to edit its contents.

To add a new user as a viewer to a Google Sheets file using the Google Sheets API, you can use the batchUpdate() method of the Google_Service_Sheets_Spreadsheets_Resource class.

Answer (score 1):

This one worked!

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/credentials.json'); // Set the path to your credentials file

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);

$drive_service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

$file_id = "YOUR_SPREADSHEET_FILE_ID"; // Replace with your spreadsheet file ID
$email_address = "USER_EMAIL_ADDRESS"; // Replace with the email address of the user you want to share with
$permission = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission();
$permission->setRole('writer'); // Replace with the role you want to give the user (e.g. "writer", "reader", "owner")
$permission->setType('user');
$permission->setEmailAddress($email_address);

try {
  $response = $drive_service->permissions->create($file_id, $permission, array('sendNotificationEmail' => false));
  printf("Permission ID: %s\n", $response->id);
} catch (Exception $e) {
  print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```